Same application, same OS version, "% of Time In GC" so high on one PC but not on other PCs
While monitoring our socket server application in Performance Monitor, I noticed that the "% of Time In GC" is significantly high (average 25-30) only on one PC (server) but not on other PCs/servers (average only 0.8) when the servers reached the same client online level.

All servers run the same .NET 4.5 application server, same version, and same configuration.
All servers use Windows Server 2019, updated to the latest build, but the issue persists.  - The server having the issue is newer in hardware, has more CPU cores, and a higher clock speed
We use only 32% of memory RAM, so there is much more memory available.
We use only 10% of the server's CPU usage, so there is ample CPU capacity remaining.
All servers use the same .NET Framework version 4.5. I have tried using other .NET Framework versions on the problematic server, such as .NET 4.7.2 and .NET 4.8, but the issue still persists.

What should I consider first that could be causing this strange issue?

Is the load identical? If one server gets a different type of call it could explain the problem. It might be a slow memory leak. I would take some memory snapshots to help investigate the problem. Using a profiler to track allocations could also be useful.

Thank you @JonasH , the load is identical. These are just load balancing servers, so they share the same clients, the same load, and the same kind of calls. I repeated this test multiple times; even with a much smaller load, I can see the issue.

I just took a full dump of the application server that is having issues and compared it with another server that is working normally. I loaded both dumps into WinDbg. Then, I ran !dumpheap -stat and compared the results. Both servers look almost similar. However, I don't understand why the "% time in GC" is so different.

Ok, it took me a lot of time to figure this out.
When I opened the folder containing the executable file, I somehow mistakenly renamed the MyApplication.exe.config file to MyApplication.config. I didn’t realize this and had no memory of doing it.
The config file contains the gcServer and gcConcurrent settings enabled. After renaming the file back, the issue was resolved, and the %GC in time is now a very small number.
I am leaving my solution here for anyone who makes the same mistake. I will have to edit my code to check if the config file exists before continuing to prevent this mistake from occurring in the future as the .exe.config file is so important.
